# c++ bubble sort compact pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, bubble-sort

Im trying to implement a bubble sort with compact pointers.  The sort seems to only sort the first two and then fails when trying to use DisplayValues driver supplied by the teacher

```
  float *Sort(float *first, size_t elements)
{
    {
        for (didSwap = 0, current = first, next = first + 1; current < last; ++current, ++next)
        {
                 didSwap = 1;
            }
        }
        --last;
    }
    while (didSwap);

    return first;
}
```

Comment: It looks as if the test and the sort employ different sort directions. That said, what the heck are "compact pointers" and "the first two"? Mostly this question no sense.

Comment: Now let me guess, I think your professor was a C programmer before he learned the minimum possible C++ he could get away with. I'm sure you class is very good, but please don't think you learning C++ here.

Comment: `while (didSwap);` -- intentional?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple, the professors routine is expecting the array to be in descending order. Your code looks correct to me but it sorts to ascending order.

BTW your professor has a misunderstanding about how `setiosflags` works. It should be

```
cout << setiosflags(ios_base::fixed);
```

to set the flags on the `cout` stream. Each stream has it's own flags, your professor seems to be under impression that there is one global set of flags. Same error for `resetiosflags`.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't there be a 'do' to make that a 'do{...}while block?

```
float *Sort(float *first, size_t elements)
{
    do
    {
        for (didSwap = 0, current = first, next = first + 1; current < last; ++current, ++next)
        {
             didSwap = 1;
        }

        --last;
    }
    while (didSwap);
}
```